# Passing java an argument while debugging in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I need to pass an argument to the java command when running my Java program. This argument is "-Dderby.system.home=D:\DataDir", telling Java where the Derby database is located. In Eclipse I can simply add the argument in the Run Configuration, but how to do this in VS Code eludes me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2167#issuecomment-173864770 , pass the arguments as individual string elements

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have the `Java Extension Pack` installed.

Once you attempt to run the java file containing your main, you should see a file `launch.json` generated. If you open it with the editor, you will then be able to add multiple flags into the run `configurations`.

One of the flags that you can add is `vmArgs` And vmArgs according to their docs:

> vmArgs - The extra options and system properties for the JVM (for
>   example -Xms -Xmx -D=), it accepts a string
>   or an array of string.

More info: [visualstudio docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging)

Comment: Right, found that in the docs. But that's referring to arguments to be passed to the program's main() method, not to the JRE. This argument is to tell Java where to find the Derby database, so actually running the program as a jar file will be:

    java -Dderby.system.home=D:\DataDir -jar MyProgram.jar

Comment: vmArgs is the one you're looking for then right? Updated my answer.

Comment: It sure seems like that's what I need, but I guess I'm not using the right syntax. I tried: "vmargs": "-Dderby.system.home=D:\\DataDir" and the program isn't finding the database. That's the syntax that's used running program from the command line ... I wonder if internally VS Code isn't simply adding that argument to the 'java' command.

Comment: `"vmArgs": "-Dderby.system.home=D:\\DataDir"` - note the camelCase on `vmArgs`

Comment: Sheesh. I'd used camel case in the settings, it just didn't make it over to my last comment :-/ So sorry. The line copy/pasted exactly as entered in my launch.json file is: "vmArgs": "-Dderby.system.home=D:\\DataDir". Results are as they were, getting an exception that the database file isn't found.

Comment: Something I noticed before, which made me mention about whether VS Code is using this as expected internally, is that the resulting command in the terminal doesn't include this argument, though there is a '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' argument. I'm missing something fundamental here ...

Answer (score 8):

For me, it was adding the args array to the config as below.

This passes in "-G" as the argument.

```
{
  "type": "java",
  "name": "Launch CommandLineController",
  "request": "launch",            
  "args": 
  [
      "-G"
  ],            
  "mainClass": "com.eric.controller.CommandLineController",      
  "projectName": "quotes"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this solution is applicable if you're passing vmArgs in launch.json directly, but I ran into trouble when using settings.json

When you go to Settings > Launch in VSCode, it brings you to settings.json, where it automatically adds the following boilerplate:

```
"launch": {
    "configurations": [],
    "compounds": []
}
```

Following the documentation, I modified it with the necessary vmArgs to launch my application:

```
"launch": {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--foo arg1 --bar arg2",
            "mainClass": "baz.Klass",
            "projectName": "baz"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

What I didn't know is that this configuration gets copied over to launch.json when attempting to run the application. It appears launch.json is what's actually used when configuring the app, however, not every entry gets copied over properly (notably vmArgs).

Before attempting to launch my app, there was no launch.json file in my .vscode directory. After attempting to launch my app, the launch.json file was created with the following content:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "baz.Klass",
            "projectName": "baz_ca302835"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--foo arg1 --bar arg2",
            "mainClass": "baz.Klass",
            "projectName": "baz"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I simply had to copy the vmArgs from the second configuration object to the first configuration object, and the application was successfully invoked with the proper command line arguments.

If you check your terminal and see that the vmArgs aren't present when your app is invoked, this solution *might* be applicable, as this was the case for me before I copied them into the first configuration object in launch.json

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug unit tests using the Java Test Runner extension, then you'll need to update your settings.json. Add the following section:

```
"java.test.config": {
    "vmArgs": [
        "-Dderby.system.home=D:\DataDir"
    ]
}
```

More can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing